# ContentProvider appropriate for very dynamic data?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm an Android newbie, learning the SDK by creating some basic apps. I'm currently working on an app that will display content from a news aggregator with news items and comments on each item. Each news item has an 'id', and many comments associated with it.

Each results page will have a 'before' and 'after' reference id to the news item at the beginning of the page and the end, respectively. So each 'query' will be something like '/?before=$ID' or '/?after=$ID'.

It seems like ContentProviders are the preferred way to store data on android. However, the content of the site changes so much that I question whether or not using a ContentProvider would be wise.

I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Well content providers are used by the e-mail app to hold e-mail, gmail to store and sync its mail messages, gtalk and contacts to keep track of the people you know and their chat status, etc.

I am not sure just how dynamic you are thinking, but those are all pretty dynamic.

One way to look at it -- a content provider is just an API to access structured data across processes.  If that API serves your purpose, well that's a good sign.  The other aspect to them is that *usually* they are implemented on top of a SQLite database, and that is the easiest way to implement them because there is a lot of framework support for that.  So you will most likely be using a SQLite database for your content provider impl.  Is a database dynamic enough for you?